# Value of Yojana in Sayana's commentary on Rig Veda

Tags: vedas, history, rig-veda

In his commentary on Rig-Veda, Sayana has talked about speed of light in terms of "Yojana". Historically, this term has had many different interpretations as described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yojana).

So what was the value of Yojana that Sayana used? Are there any clues or contemporary references which indicate the value?